# how to set rounded corners with background tansparency object in android shape xml

Tags: android, rounded-corners, android-shape

I m tying to get rounded corners with background color in shape xml file. But its not working with corners. Here is the output of the code

[image]

And here is the code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#aaffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>

        <shape>

        <corners
            android:radius="11dp"   >
        </corners>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

A quick help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#aaffffff" />
         <corners android:radius="11dp"   />
    </shape>
</item>
```